# Plot linear regression analysis with error bar for variability

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, errorbar

I wanted to make plots that look like figure 1 (source: [link](http://blogs.cornell.edu/whatscroppingup/2019/02/21/soil-health-indicators-can-be-correlated-to-agronomic-management-and-crop-yield/))

[image]

In figure 1, they have plotted the regression analysis with one-year yield variability. In my case, I would like to plot variability between two locations and 4 blocks for each treatment group. So the plot I wanted would have three facets for factors `B.glucosidase`, `Protein`, `POX.C` of `variable` and four colors for treatments factors. Also, in my current plot I have legend for block and treatment. I should only have treatment because the block should be used for making error bar for variability.

I tried with this code, which obviously doesn't work for what I want. (Data for `df.melted` included below.)

```
ggplot(df.melted, aes(x = value, y = yield, color = as.factor(treatment))) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape= as.factor(block))) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, col = "darkslategrey", se=F) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y~x, 
               # aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               aes(label =  ..rr.label..), 
               parse = TRUE) + 
  theme_classic() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = df.melted$yield+sd(df.melted$yield), ymin = df.melted$yield-sd(df.melted$yield)), width = 0.05)+
facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Data:

```
df.melted <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("M", "U"), class = "factor"), 
    treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("CC", 
    "CCS", "CS", "SCS"), class = "factor"), block = c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), yield = c(5156L, 5157L, 5551L, 5156L, 4804L, 
    4720L, 4757L, 5021L, 4826L, 4807L, 4475L, 4596L, 4669L, 4588L, 
    4542L, 4592L, 5583L, 5442L, 5693L, 5739L, 5045L, 4902L, 5006L, 
    5086L, 4639L, 4781L, 4934L, 4857L, 4537L, 4890L, 4842L, 4608L, 
    5156L, 5157L, 5551L, 5156L, 4804L, 4720L, 4757L, 5021L, 4826L, 
    4807L, 4475L, 4596L, 4669L, 4588L, 4542L, 4592L, 5583L, 5442L, 
    5693L, 5739L, 5045L, 4902L, 5006L, 5086L, 4639L, 4781L, 4934L, 
    4857L, 4537L, 4890L, 4842L, 4608L, 5156L, 5157L, 5551L, 5156L, 
    4804L, 4720L, 4757L, 5021L, 4826L, 4807L, 4475L, 4596L, 4669L, 
    4588L, 4542L, 4592L, 5583L, 5442L, 5693L, 5739L, 5045L, 4902L, 
    5006L, 5086L, 4639L, 4781L, 4934L, 4857L, 4537L, 4890L, 4842L, 
    4608L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B.glucosidase", 
    "Protein", "POX.C"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.600946, 
    1.474084, 1.433078, 1.532492, 1.198667, 1.193193, 1.214941, 
    1.360981, 1.853056, 1.690117, 1.544357, 1.825132, 1.695409, 
    1.764123, 1.903743, 1.538684, 0.845077, 1.011463, 0.857032, 
    0.989803, 0.859022, 0.919467, 1.01717, 0.861689, 0.972332, 
    0.952922, 0.804431, 0.742634, 1.195837, 1.267285, 1.08571, 
    1.20097, 6212.631579, 5641.403509, 4392.280702, 7120.701754, 
    5305.964912, 4936.842105, 5383.157895, 6077.894737, 5769.122807, 
    5016.842105, 5060.350877, 5967.017544, 5576.842105, 5174.035088, 
    5655.438596, 5468.77193, 7933.333333, 7000, 6352.982456, 
    8153.684211, 6077.894737, 4939.649123, 5002.807018, 6489.122807, 
    4694.035088, 5901.052632, 4303.859649, 6768.421053, 6159.298246, 
    6090.526316, 4939.649123, 5262.45614, 810.3024, 835.5242, 
    856.206, 759.8589, 726.2298, 792.6472, 724.7165, 699.3266, 
    500.9153, 634.8698, 637.9536, 648.8814, 641.0357, 623.3822, 
    555.2834, 520.8119, 683.3528, 595.9173, 635.4315, 672.4234, 
    847.2944, 745.5665, 778.3548, 735.8141, 395.2647, 570.4148, 
    458.0383, 535.3851, 678.0293, 670.7419, 335.2923, 562.5674
    )), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you give a little more information about how you're calculating the error bars?

Comment: @cardinal40 The way I have done is not correct. It should be first grouped by the same treatment group (including both locations and all four blocks) and then calculate the error bars.

Comment: Here's an initial run that gets the colors and shapes while removing the legend for block: ```df.melted %>% 
  mutate(
    block = factor(block),
    treatment = factor(treatment)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = yield)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = treatment, shape = block)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "darkslategrey") + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free") +
  scale_shape(guide = "none")```

Comment: So do you will want to get eight separate calculations for mean and SD, one for each location/block pair?

Comment: @cardinal40 I think you are close, but instead of all these shapes, can we have error bar for these shapes? So error bars made out of 4 shapes.

Comment: There will be four dots only (and error bars for four dots) per facet.

Comment: I'm still confused about what you want... maybe you could create a new data frame with the calculations needed for the error bars and get the information that way.

Comment: So for error bars, we will calculate based on 2 locations and 4 blocks, so for example, for treatment `CC` we will have error bar calculate based on U and M locations and blocks 1:4. In each figure, there will be only 4 dots (right now you have 32 dots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
```

Summarize data frame (this could also be done with `stat_summary()`, but it's often clearer/more transparent to do it explicitly up front). (I think that because your data set is balanced you could collapse/average over the block structure first, and then do your whole plot with the reduced data set - it shouldn't change the outcome of the linear regressions at all, at least not the mean values ... and any statistical comparisons should probably done on block-level summaries anyway ...)

```
df.sum <- (df.melted
    %>% group_by(Location,treatment,variable)
    %>% summarise(value=mean(value),yield_sd=sd(yield),
                  ## collapse yield to mean *after* computing sd!
                  yield=mean(yield))
)
```

Plot:

```
(ggplot(df.melted,
       aes(x = value, y = yield, color = treatment))
    + stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "darkslategrey", se=FALSE)
    + stat_poly_eq(
          formula = y ~ x,
          ## aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
          aes(group=1, label =  ..rr.label..), 
          parse = TRUE)
    + theme_classic()
    + scale_shape(guide=FALSE)
    + geom_point(data=df.sum)
    + geom_errorbar(data=df.sum,
                    aes(ymax = yield+yield_sd, ymin = yield-yield_sd),
                    width = 0.05)
    + facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_x")
)
```

(adding `group=1` to the `stat_poly_eq()` aesthetics means we only plot a single R^2 value per facet)

[image]

Since you're no longer using the shape aesthetic for anything, you could consider using it to show the Location variable ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question- how do you account for locations as well? There are 8 data points in your plot, but I only wanted 4 points one for each treatment and only one R-square value per facet.

Comment: I think this solved the problem of 8 data points `df.sum <- (df.melted
           %>% group_by(treatment,variable)
           %>% summarise(value=mean(value),yield_sd=sd(yield),
                         ## collapse yield to mean *after* computing sd!
                         yield=mean(yield))
)` , but still I only want only one R-sq value per facet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.